# $(window)on.('load') Function Works on Firefox, but Not on Safari/iOS or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-chrome, safari

I'm not certain of the reason, but this particular function does not seem to be working in both the Safari/iOS and Chrome browsers:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  $('#preloader').fadeOut(800).hide();
  $('#preload').fadeIn(800).css('display', 'initial').show();
});
```

I've currently inserted the script before the `</head>` tag. Could anyone explain why this is occurring?

**UPDATE:**

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut(800).hide();
  $('#preload').fadeIn(800).css('display', 'initial').show();
});
```

```css
.preloader-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

#preloader {
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

#preload {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/4m2ikeh/q2Poxnx2k/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="preloader-wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn.ndtv.com/vp/static/images/preloader.gif" id="preloader" />
</div>

<div id="preload">
  <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/708bb6dcdaf359fd2ea83d11a0b5b4b8/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco10_r1_1280.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `$(document).ready()` instead?

Comment: @Barmar No. This preloading function doesn't activate unless I use `$(window).on('load',function()`; but even so, though it does work on Firefox, the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` calls don't seem to execute in Safari or Chrome...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do when you have both `fadeOut()` and `hide()` on the same element. `fadeOut()` means to hide slowly, but `hide()` hides immediately.

Comment: And `fadeIn()`, `css('display', 'initial')`, and `show()` all show the element.

Comment: @Barmar It is because I want there to be a short delay from when the content is being loaded, (this displays the preloader, but then fades out after an instance.)

Comment: Can you make a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: But there's no delay with `hide()` and `show()`.

Comment: What's the difference between `#preloader` and `#preload`?

Comment: @Barmar the `#preloader` is the preloader image that will eventually fade out and be replaced by the `#preload` content, which will eventually fade in.

Comment: Please post an MCVE that we can test.

Comment: @Barmar I have provided a snippet.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, this particular snippet works now; however, I still cannot get this to work on the site I am currently working on, strange... It must be another issue then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use hide() when you use fadeOut() and show() when you use fadeIn(). However have a look at here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#preloader").fadeOut(800, function() {
    $("#preload").fadeIn(800)
  });
});
```

```css
#preload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  Preloader Content
</div>
<div id="preload">
  Preload Content
</div>
```

It is working for me in Firefox, Chrome, Safari

Comment: `fadeIn()` should be on `#preload`, not `#preloader`.

Comment: @csskevin Thanks. This is the closest solution to what I was looking for. I'll have to work with it a little, but it seems to be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those multiple concurring ways to show and hide the elements are in cause. I don't have any IOS device to be sure.

If you wish a delay and the fades one after the other, try this way:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut(800, function(){
      $('#preload').fadeIn(800);  // FadeIn after fadeOut complete.
    });
  },800);  // delay from the load event and the fadeOut.
});
```

Comment: I think the `load` event occurs after `DOMContentLoaded`. So why would it work better with an earlier event?